# Jquery Cloning for Radio Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi Could any one explain me how to perform **jquery cloning** operation for radio buttons.
I have two Radio buttons like Optional,Compulsory by default optional one is checked.In jquery cloning two radio buttons are creating but by default one(Optional) is not checking.how to make by default one checked in cloning operation please help me out its urgent.thanks in advance

**In jsp:**

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <label class="control-label" for="typeahead">Transport Approval<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="hidden" value="transportcombo" name="approval"/>     
<input type="hidden" value="transportbtn" name="checkapproval"/>  
<tr>
   <td></td>
  <td>
    <select name="transportcombo" id="transportcombo" onchange="validatecombo('transportcombo',this);">
      <option value="-1">Select</option>
      <%
        for (EmployeeEntity elem : list) {
      %>
        <option value="<%= elem.getEmployeeid()%>"><%= elem.getFirstname()%></option> 
      <%
        }
      %>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="radio"  checked="" value="Optional" name="transportbtn1"/>Optional                                        
    <input type="radio" value="Compulsory" name="transportbtn1"/>compulsory
  </td>         
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr >
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td >
    <button type="button"  value="2" id="transportbtn" class="btn-primary"  onclick="insertCombo('transportbtn','transportcombo')">Add New</button> </td>
</tr>
```

**in Js File**

```
function insertCombo(id,comboid){     
    radioid= $("#"+id).val();  
    var remve = '<td><button type="button" id="btn" name='+id+' class="transclass" class="btn btn-info" >x</button></td>';
    var checkbox='<td><input type="radio"  value="Optional" id='+id+radioid+' name='+id+radioid+' checked="checked">  Optional  <input type="radio" id='+id+radioid+' value="Compulsory" name='+id+radioid+'>  compulsory</td>';
    $('#'+id).closest('tr').prev('tr').clone(true).insertAfter($('#'+id).closest('tr').prev('tr')).find('td:last-child').remove();
    $('#'+id).closest('tr').prev('tr').find('td:last-child').remove();
    $('#'+id).closest('tr').prev('tr').append(checkbox).attr(id+radioid,"checked").append(remve); 
    var innerid=0;

    $('select[name^='+comboid+']').each(function () {       
        this.id=++innerid;
    });  
    $('input[name^='+id+radioid+']').each( function () {
    $('input[name="' +id+radioid+ '"]').prop('checked',true);
    });    
    document.getElementById(id).value=++radioid;
}
```

Comment: ya when i click add new button in jsp file automatically one dropdownbox and two radio buttons are generating but i need one radio button checked

Comment: ya i used that already its not  checking